# Error when solving differential equation. (Initial Condition of a Multivariable Function)

Tags: differential-equations

[[image][Mathematical Expressions, BC and IC are boundary and initial conditions]

Mathematica returns the following error "NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently." for the following code. The picture above describes the math I am trying to solve. (This is a physics problem) I would appreciate any help.

-Constants-

```
r = 0.02;
A = Pi r^2;
Diff = 20;
k1 = 83.5;
k = 1;
m = 0.05;
c = 449.4 m;
R = 8.3145;
Qsys = 10;
T0 = 298;
l = 0.10;
M = 0.3;
P0 = 101325;
n = (P0 A (2 l))/(R T0);
```

-Equations-

```
eq1 = D[T[x, t], t] == 
   Diff D[T[x, t], t, t] - D[v[x, t] T[x, t], t] - k (T[x, t] - T0);
eq2 = D[Th[t], t] == Qsys/c - (k1 A (Th[t] - T[l, t]))/(c l);
eq3 = Diff (D[T[x, t], t, t] /. x -> (l + L[t])) - (D[v[x, t] T[x, t],
        t] /. x -> (l + L[t])) - k (T[l + L[t], t] - T0) == 
   M L'[t] L''[t];
eq4 = (D[T[x, t], t] /. x -> l) == (k1 A (Th[t] - T[l, t]))/(c l) + 
    Diff (D[T[x, t], t, t] /. x -> (l)) - (D[v[x, t] T[x, t], t] /. 
      x -> (l)) - k (T[l, t] - T0);
eq5 = T[l + l[t], t] == T0;
eq6 = D[T[x, t]/P[x, t], t] + D[T[x, t]/P[x, t] v[x, t], x] == 0;
eq7 = Integrate[P[x, t], {x, 0, l + L[t]}] A (l + L[t]) == 
   n R Integrate[T[x, t], {x, 0, l + L[t]}];
eq8 = D[v[x, t], t] == n R T[x, t]/P[x, t] D[P[x, t], x];
```

-Boundary Conditions and Initial Conditions-

```
bc1 = v[l, t] == 0;
ic1 = L[0] == l;
ic2 = Th[0] == T0;
ic3 = T[l, 0] == T0;
ic4 = P[x, 0] == P0;
ic5 = v[x, 0] == 0;
```

Returns error at

```
NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, bc1, ic1, ic2, ic3, 
  ic4, ic5}, {Th, T, L, v, P}, {x, l, 2 l}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: All the dependent variables should have the same arguments

Comment: We can't solve this problem with `NDSolve`. If you like to solve your problem with novel method, please, add mathematical formulas in Latex form with explanation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev   I unfortunately don't know how to use Latex. I tried my best to write the expressions down on the image I added. Would this help? Thank you.

Comment: @user90149 Could you explain in words what do you try to solve?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am trying to solve for L[x] and P[x,t] by  either Ndsolve or Dsolve.

Comment: @AlexTrounev If you need a more precise explanation, let me know. I will try my best to explain.

Comment: @user90149 Yes, please, explain more precisely.

Comment: @AlexTrounev     Should I give you an explanation about the physical system? Mathematically there are 5 functions (3 dependent on t and x, 2 dependent on only t) 9 differential equations. Also with 1 boundary condition and 5 initial conditions for all the 5 functions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I have just typed the mathematical equations in the pictures to mathematica

Comment: @user90149 What is the physical system do you try to simulate?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am trying to model an Thermo Acoustic Engine, it is well explained in the following video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abswNCqnMRQ&ab_channel=NightHawkInLight

Comment: @AlexTrounev      So, I am trying to calculate how much the engine extends at a certain time. Therefore the function L[t] I have represents to length the heat engine extends and does work.

Comment: Th[t] is the temperature of the heat source,
T[x,t] is the temperature of the gas molecules inside the engine
L[t] represents how much the engine expanded (function of length)
v[x,t] and P[x,t] are velcoity and pressure of the molecules inside the engine.

Also we are modeling in 1D, (in a straight line, assuming all moelcules lie on a line) therefore we only used on variable (x) to represent the space dependence of the functions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev        Is it unsolveable? Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @user90149 If you try to simulate thermoacoustic waves, then your system is not correct.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Can you explain why? I am having a hard time trying to model the physics of the system. Do I need more equations or are there any equations that are falsely written?

Comment: @user90149 Continuity equation has a typo. Did you seen any paper like this one https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931017347610 ?